# Unable to install Intel i586 library (Intel galileo gen 2) in Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, intel, arduino

I followed the instructions for installation of the latest Arduino IDE 1.6.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from this blog post (http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/11/install-arduino-ide-1-6-6-ubuntu/). Everything went well.

But after installation, I tried installing Intel i586 library as I own an intel galileo gen 2 board. Every time I try to install the library I get this error message:
[image: error message]
As a result, I’m also not able to compile and run sketches to my board.

Here is the list of warning message I got in compilation window of IDE while I was installing the library.

```
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/etc/ld.so.cache links to an absolute path /etc/ld.so.cache
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/ranlib links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-ranlib
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/nm links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-nm
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/strip links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-strip
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/cpp links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-cpp
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/ar links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-ar
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/objcopy links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-objcopy
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/gcc links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-gcc
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/objdump links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-objdump
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/ld links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-ld
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/gcc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/4.7.2/as links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/i586-poky-linux-uclibc-as
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/opkg links to an absolute path /opt/clanton-tiny/1.4.4/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/opkg-cl
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/usr/src/debug/libgcc/4.7.2-r20/build/libgcc/gthr-default.h links to an absolute path /jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_1.0.5-Toolchain-Linux64/yocto_build/tmp/work-shared/gcc-4.7.2-r20/gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/gthr-posix.h
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/usr/src/debug/libgcc/4.7.2-r20/build/libgcc/unwind.h links to an absolute path /jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_1.0.5-Toolchain-Linux64/yocto_build/tmp/work-shared/gcc-4.7.2-r20/gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/unwind-generic.h
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/usr/src/debug/libgcc/4.7.2-r20/build/libgcc/enable-execute-stack.c links to an absolute path /jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_1.0.5-Toolchain-Linux64/yocto_build/tmp/work-shared/gcc-4.7.2-r20/gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/enable-execute-stack-empty.c
Warning: file /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/sysroots/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/usr/src/debug/libgcc/4.7.2-r20/build/libgcc/md-unwind-support.h links to an absolute path /jenkins_builder/workspace/GLLO_1.0.5-Toolchain-Linux64/yocto_build/tmp/work-shared/gcc-4.7.2-r20/gcc-4.7.2/libgcc/config/i386/linux-unwind.h
Setting it up.../tmp/tmp.iPSRXYmbqY/relocate_sdk.sh /home/rishi/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586/relocate_sdk.sh
SDK could not be set up. Relocate script failed. Abort!
find: invalid mode ‘+111’
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the information found at https://communities.intel.com/thread/48053?start=0&tstart=0 and thanks to sulamita and digver I could finally install and run the intel galileo gen2 board on Ubuntu 16.04

The steps I have followed are:

1. Install the board through the arduino IDE.

   - This was accomplished through the Board manager which appears on the picture you have placed on this post.
   - After installing the board an error occured, but no worries, this will be solved later.
2. Modify the files which relocate sdk.

   - Open terminal `ctrl + alt + T`
   - Acces as root user `sudo su` (and enter your password)
   - Move to the following folder `cd /root/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586`
   - Then execute the following: `gedit install_script.sh`
   - On the opened file search for the lines which start with "executable_files" and change the "+111" characters for "/111"
   - After saving, go back to the terminal and execute `./install_script.sh`

Enjoy your working intel galileo gen2 bord!

Comment: @lgnasi Sorry for the late reply. when I entered  `cd /root/.arduino15/packages/Intel/tools/i586-poky-linux-uclibc/1.6.2+1.0/i586` I got the error saying so such directory. What should I do now ?

Comment: As the target folder is inside many ohter folders it could be that one of the names of a folder is different than in my case, and thus, it leads to the `no such directory` error.

Try typing `sudo nautilus /root/.arduino15` (to open a root permission GUI) and then try to search for the "install_script.sh" files found on there.

Afterwards proceed on the 5th bullet of the second part of my guide (files can be opened by right clicking on them and "open with gedit")

Finally last bullet (right click in some free space on the folder where the file is contained and choose "open in terminal" )

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. The solution above from Ignasi is good, and very much appreciated, thank you. However in addition people who have this problem might want to do the following too:

```
sudo apt-get remove modemmanager
```

This is to remove the influence of the modem manager from interfering with the tty link (unlikely to be a problem in practice, but does seem to happen on occasion in my class of 25 students)

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout rishi
```

This is to give you sufficient permissions to write to /dev/ttyACM0 (since your username is rishi)

Comment: Sorry for a late reply !! Thak you :)

Answer (score 0):

For people that found this, and still had problems after changing the `+111` to `/111`, you might want to check if any other script within the directory is error-ing out.

For me, `relocate_sdk.py` was prefixed with `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, causing a syntax error.

Fixed that and everything is working now.